# Get return status without freezing until childs return

Tags: c, exec, fork, posix, wait

I need to run child processes exactly on defined interval. wait() after exec() messes up the timing. How can i get return values from childs without freezing the execution/messing the timing? If that is not possible or very hard then how can i discard the return value without leaving zombies?

Example code:
(the goal is to run all jobs[] at exactly 10sec intervals)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
main() {
        int i, status;
        char jobs[3][100+1];
        time_t t;
        pid_t pid;
        strncpy(jobs[0], "sleep 3", 100);
        strncpy(jobs[1], "sleep 5", 100);
        strncpy(jobs[2], "sleep 10", 100);
        while (1) {
                t = time(NULL);
                sleep(5 - t % 5);
                printf("executing jobs. time: %s", ctime(&t));
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        t = time(NULL);
                        pid = fork();
                        if (pid == 0) {
                                printf("run: %s, pid %d, time: %s\n", jobs[i], (int) getpid(), ctime(&t));
                                execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", jobs[i], (char *) NULL);
                        }
                }
                while ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0) {
                        t = time(NULL);
                        printf("job complete. pid: %d, return: %d, time: %s\n", (int) pid, status, ctime(&t));
                }
                t = time(NULL);
                printf("done. time: %s", ctime(&t));
                sleep(10);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) function instead, with the `WNOHANG` flag.

Comment: Thanks. waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED) solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `waitpid` ([here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)) with the `WNOHANG` and potentially the `WUNTRACED` options.